# debug classic asp page

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have a website in VS 2010 made using asp.net (.aspx) pages.
This website also contains a classic asp page in it.

I want to be able to debug this page.

Note: I'm just running the website from VS 2010, I'm NOT deploying it in IIS.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The standard way to debug classic asp is through friendly error messages on the webpage. If you need to use a development server the one which comes with VS doesn't support classic asp, you need a local version of IIS or IIS express

Answer (score 0):

> you can debug vbscript file by putting "Stop"  statement in .asp file.

Please refer this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525253(v=vs.90).aspx)

**Section** : VBScript Stop Statement Debugging